# Do I need to configure certs on nginx itself if nginx is inside ec2 instance on loadbalancer which can only be accessed using https?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, https, load-balancing

I have the cert applied on the load balancer, and https works fine, but i am wondering if I need to add the certs to nginx itself, which seems overkill but i am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
No, one of the benefit of using a Load Balancer is you can hide your EC2 from public internet, making it less open and more secured.

Therefore, it is normal practice to use HTTP between your EC2 and load balancers, since they are in the same AWS Region (a safe and trusted internal environment).

By doing this you will also increase performance, because the https network overhead is only executed once in the load balancer, not twice. Your EC2 will focus the CPU resources on running the application logic instead.

Load Balancer is also Highly Available and can be configured to work with CloudFront and WAF for security and anti-DDoS controls.

Comment: Oh interesting. I did not know this or understand this clearly prior to this. IF the EC2 instance was in different region for whatever odd reason, then I would have to add ssl on the ec2 as well correct? if so, and since I can't use ACM cert on nginx, what type of cert would be most secure to add to nginx (i am thinking letsencrypt, but for production env, not sure if that is right)

Comment: If in different region , yes you better add SSL but it will slow the whole thing down because you are really doing SSL twice for every request. If possible, just deploy another ALB on that new region. The certificate `strength` is the same for Lets Encrypt with all other so called `enterprise` SSL. When done properly LE is perfect unless client wants advance feature like show company name in Chrome address bar.

Answer (score 1):

No, you **don't have to do this**. The reason is that your load balancer (LB) is going to [termiante](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-https-load-balancers.html) the https connection, decrypt it using a SSL certificate you've deployed on it, and then forward HTTP connection to your ec2 instance(s).

Therefore, typical connections for LB with HTTPS have the following form:

```
client ---(HTTPS)---->LB---(HTTP)--->EC2 instance
```

This configuration is suited for most use-cases as HTTP traffic is happening withing **AWS private network**, not over the internet.